# OpenCV corner detection returning null corners vector

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am trying to detect the corners of a chessboard image. I have tried using goodFeaturesToTrack and findChessboardCorners but they are both failing in the same way. They corner vector returned seems to be null. (i.e. size is -2948392...memory error type of stuff).

```
  gray = imread("C:/Users/Wesley/Desktop/New folder/cb.png",0);

  // Parameters for Shi-Tomasi algorithm
  std::vector<cv::Point2f> corners;
  double qualityLevel = 0.1;
  double minDistance = 10;
  int blockSize = 3;
  bool useHarrisDetector = false;
  double k = 0.04;
  int maxCorners = 30;
  Mat copy;
  copy = gray.clone();

  // Apply corner detection
  goodFeaturesToTrack(gray,
                 corners,
                 maxCorners,
                 qualityLevel,
                 minDistance,
                 Mat(),
                 blockSize,
                 useHarrisDetector,
                 k );

      int r = 4;
      for( int i = 0; i < corners.size(); i++ )
      { circle( copy, corners[i], r, Scalar(255, 255,255), -1, 8, 0 ); }

  // Show what you got
  imshow( "source_window", copy );
```

It must be something I am doing wrong. It crashes as soon as corners.size() is called due to a memory access violation. This is in Qt if it makes any difference.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction!

Comment: are building in release mode and linking against debug libraries or vice versa?

Comment: have you debugged into it and found which line it breaks on

Comment: can you add if(gray.empty()) return 0;  right after the imread?

Comment: @Micka silly me, you are correct. If you reply to the post I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check that you aren't compiling in release mode but linking against debug mode or vice versa.

OpenCV gives you the strangest behaviour if you link against the wrong libraries.